# Mysql error syntax from code sql line command error

Tags: mysql

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE Poster (
->   id smallint(6) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
->   titre VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
->   description text NOT NULL,
->   image_link text NOT NULL,
->   nb_commentaires int unsigned,
->   nb_likes int unsigned,
->   user_id smallint(6) DEFAULT NOT NULL,
->   date_cree timestamp,
->   PRIMARY KEY (id) NOT NULL,
-> ) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NOT NULL,
> date_cree timestamp,
> PRIMARY KEY (id) NOT NULL,
> ) ENGINE=InnoDB' at line 8
> mysql>

Answer (score 0):

If you define a `default` value then do it after allowing `NULL` or not

```
user_id smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
```

Also change this

```
PRIMARY KEY (id) NOT NULL,
```

to that

```
PRIMARY KEY (id)
```

complete statement:

```
 CREATE TABLE Poster 
 (
    id smallint(6) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    titre VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    description text NOT NULL,
    image_link text NOT NULL,
    nb_commentaires int unsigned,
    nb_likes int unsigned,
    user_id smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    date_cree timestamp,
    PRIMARY KEY (id) 
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```